# Elasticsearch plugin on Kubernetes

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I need to restart the Elasticsearch node after installing the injest-attachment plugin on Kubernetes Engine on Google Cloud Platform. I have deployed Elasticsearch on a pod. What is the best way to restart the Elasticsearch nodes?

Answer (score 2):

If Elasticsearch is running directly on the VM:

```
systemctl restart elasticsearch
```

If Elasticsearch is running as a container on docker:

```
docker restart <container-id>
```

If Elasticsearch is running as a Kubernetes pod (deployed through a Kubernetes manifest):

- update the image tag in the manifest if needed, and do `kubectl apply`
- Or use `kubectl replace` or `kubectl edit` commands

On Kubernetes, ideally, you should use the declarative way of updating the manifests and then do a `kubectl apply -f`

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed elasticsearch with a replication set, Kubernetes will enforce the number of desired pods automatically so you can simply kill the existing pod and a new one can be created.

```
kubectl delete pods example-pod-1812877987
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when installing the ltr plugin on a Minikube deployment of Elasticsearch.

Following the instructions of using initContainer to install the plugin [1] did not work since I could not figure out how to restart Elasticsearch after plugin installation since I was not able to get root access to the elasticsearch pod.

However, following the instructions on how to build a custom image containig the plugin [2] did solve my problem since in that way the plugin is installed before elasticsearch is started.

[1] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-bundles-plugins.html

[2] https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-custom-images.html